# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a function (for composite components).Check the render method of `SelectProfileContainer`

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have one problem in index.js, it looks that i have error with export and import, I've checked my code but I can't find the bug. any help please?

I'm getting this error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `SelectProfileContainer`

My react code (index.js):

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "normalize.css";
import App from "./app";
import { GlobalStyles } from "./global-styles";
import { firebase } from "./lib/firebase.prod";
import { FirebaseContext } from "./context/firebase";
render(
  <>

    <FirebaseContext.Provider value={{ firebase }}>

      <GlobalStyles />

      <App />

    </FirebaseContext.Provider>
  </>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

here is GlobalStyles.js code:

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";

export const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`
html, body {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    background-color: black;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

here is what gives the browser:

> Check the render method of `SelectProfileContainer`.
>
> ▶ 23 stack frames were collapsed.
>
> Module.
>
> C:/Users/CPU-MAJD/OneDrive/Desktop/Completely_fully_Netflix-clone/netflix/src/index.js:9
>
> 6 | import { firebase } from "./lib/firebase.prod";
>
> 7 | import { FirebaseContext } from "./context/firebase";
>
> 8 |
>
> >  9 | render(
>
> 10 |   <>
>
> 11 |     <FirebaseContext.Provider value={{ firebase }}>
>
> 12 |

Comment: So, have you checked the render method of `SelectProfileContainer`?

Comment: I can't find the component `SelectProfileContainer`. I didn't create this function

Comment: you can check my code here https://github.com/Gloryyy/Netflix-clone-from-scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking your repo, I can see the `SelectProfileContainer` component:

```
export function SelectProfileContainer({ user, setProfile }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Header bg={false}>
        <Header.Frame>
          <Header.Logo to={ROUTES.HOME} src={logo} alt="Netflix" />
        </Header.Frame>
      </Header>

      <Profiles>
        <Profiles.Title>Who's watching?</Profiles.Title>
        <Profiles.List>
          <Profiles.User
            onClick={() =>
              setProfile({
                displayName: user.displayName,
                photoURL: user.photoURL,
              })
            }
          >
            <Profiles.Picture src={user.photoURL} />
            <Profiles.Name>{user.displayName}</Profiles.Name>
          </Profiles.User>
        </Profiles.List>
      </Profiles>
    </>
  );
}
```

The error message rendered on the screen is not really helpful but if you check the console you can see the following one which is more useful:

```
Check your code at profiles.js:19.
    at SelectProfileContainer
```

[Line 19](https://github.com/Gloryyy/Netflix-clone-from-scratch/blob/master/src/containers/profiles.js#L19) is the one with `<Profiles.User>` and if you try to check the component, you will notice that it doesn't exist in `src/components/profiles/index.js`. Make sure there is a `<Profiles.User>` component and the error is gone.

Comment: Zsolt Meszaros finally it works fine thanks bro, actually I forgot to rename `<Profiles.User>` to `<Profiles.Item>` that was the error. thanks so much